# No perldoc for POSIX?

Tags: arch-linux, perl

On some other systems, like Ubuntu, `perldoc POSIX` works, but on Arch,

```
%> perldoc POSIX
No documentation found for "POSIX".

%> perldoc /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/POSIX.pm
No documentation found for "/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/POSIX.pm".
```

Did I missed some packages? Other libaries like `LWP::UserAgent` works through.

Comment: On ubuntu it's a seperate package, `perl-doc`. Probably the same on arch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core `perldoc` comes with the [perl package in arch](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/i686/perl/). e.g. `perldoc perllol`. For most modules all the utility does is build the documentation from the POD in the source though.  `/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/POSIX.pm` happens to have no POD so doesn't build any documentation. I guess because it is an XS module so most of it's function is in C somewhere else.

Comparing Arch to a Debian box with perldoc, on Debian some of the core modules also have a separate `.pod` file in `/usr/share/perl/5.x/` whereas Arch has none.

POSIX.pm seems to be slightly different again in that the `.pod` is in the lib directory..

```
debian$ find /usr/lib/ -name "*.pod"
/usr/lib/perl/5.10.1/Config.pod
/usr/lib/perl/5.10.1/POSIX.pod
```

Which makes it look like debian does something custom here.

In fact, if you check the [perl source](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/tree/45ed5e1b00da4aecc4751dbc6583302752186d25:/ext/POSIX/lib) `POSIX.pod` is a separate file sitting next to the perl module.

Maybe [file a bug with arch](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/i686/perl/) to have it included? I guess you could argue for it to be changed in Perl instead, if it goes against some standard. There's Perl people on stackoverflow that would probably know.

Comment: Yeah, I checked the PKGBUILD, all *.pod files are deleted on purpose, I'd fire a bug report, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference is to use the [online documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/), selecting the Perl version appropriately.  For your specific questions about the `POSIX` core module there is [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html).  For non-core Perl modules look to [metacpan](https://metacpan.org/) for documentation, viewing the source code and/or downloads, of course.